# Getting method is undefined in C++

Tags: c++, undefined-function

I'm trying to create a program from a C++ tutorial. But the IDE the tutor is using is VS2010 and I'm using VS2017. I noticed some of the syntaxes(sp.) are slightly different. I'm not sure what this error is and I've tried searching.

Here's the main .cpp:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Utility.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int x;
        cout << "Enter a Number: " << endl;
        cin >> x;

        if (IsPrime(x))
            cout << x << " is prime" << endl;
        else
            cout << x << " is not prime" << endl;

        if (Is2MorePrime(x))
            cout << x << "+2 is prime" << endl;
        else
            cout << x << "+2 is not prime" << endl;


        return 0;
    }
```

The methods being tested out in the if conditions are both returning a "*included method*: identifier not found" and "*included method*: identifier is undefined"

Here's the included class .cpp:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Utility.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;


    bool Utility::IsPrime(int num)
    {
    bool prime = true;
        for (int i = 0; i <= num / i; i++)
        {
            int factor = num / i;
            if (factor*i == num)
            {
                cout << "Factor Found: " << factor << endl;
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return prime;
    }

    bool Utility::Is2MorePrime(int num)
    {
        num += 2;
        return IsPrime(num);
    }
```

And here's the included header file:

```
    #pragma once

    class Utility
    {
        bool IsPrime(int primeNum);

        bool Is2MorePrime(int morePrime);
    };
```

I'm still new to C++ programming so I don't know anything intensive yet.

Comment: You are getting an error because `main` calls `IsPrime`, but there is no such function -- only `Utility::IsPrime`. You are creating a class `Utility` where you do not need one. `IsPrime` and `Is2MorePrime` should simply be functions defined in the header and implemented in the .cpp.

Comment: You're using a class as a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods are in the `Utility` class yet you are calling them from `main` with no instance of `Utility` so the compiler/linker is looking for methods that don't exist.

You could probably make them static members of `Utility` and then you just need to scope the calls (e.g. `Utility::IsPrime(x)`) and not actually have an instance of `Utility`.

As mentioned by @Amadeus in the comments: If everything in `Utility` is "stateless" and can be static, then perhaps you should be putting all the Utility methods in a namespace instead of a class.

Comment: Thank you so much @John3136. I made the methods static in the header file (e.g. `static bool IsPrime(int x)`) and scoped the calls (e.g. `if (Utility::IsPrime(x))`) like you said and it worked.